# Switching out the 'this' pointer for a static class member in the constructor

Tags: c#

Suppose I had a class with static members of itself, just like a singleton.
I also allow the construction of that class.
If a consumer constructs with known arguments I want to return a static member instead of a new construction.

Below is non compiling example code that illustrates the point.
Essentially I want the class to be constructed like illustrated in the `Construct` method but I do not want the consumer of the class to be forced into rewriting his existing `new MyClass(0)` calls.

Is that possible?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static readonly MyClass Zero = new MyClass(0);

    private int n;

    public static MyClass Construct(int n)
    {
        MyClass self = new MyClass(0, true); //the bool just helps with referencing
        ReplaceIfZero(ref self);
        return self;
    }

    public MyClass(int n, bool x) //the bool is just so i can reference it in this example
    {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public MyClass(int n)
    {
        this.n = n;
        ReplaceIfZero(ref this); 
        // Error CS1605  Cannot pass 'this' as a ref or out argument because it is read - only
    }

    ReplaceIfZero(ref MyClass myclass)
    {
        if(Zero.Equals(myclass))
        {
            myclass = Zero;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(this, obj) || ( (obj is MyClass) && n.Equals((obj as MyClass).n) );
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to change the result of `new` operator. You need to remove the public constructor and force your clients to use some public static factory method like `MyClass.Create`

Comment: @IvanStoev : you should make an answer out of your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal solution to this is to make the constructor private and add a public static factory method that takes care of things. I think that would be the best approach.

However, another approach is the use an interface and a wrapper class to hide away the details.

Something like this:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    int SomeMethod(int x);
}

public class MyClass: IMyClass
{
    public MyClass(int n)
    {
        _impl = MyClassImpl.Create(n);
    }

    public int SomeMethod(int x)
    {
        return _impl.SomeMethod(x);
    }

    // For test purposes only - see later in this answer.
    public bool ImplementationEquals(MyClass other)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(_impl, other._impl);
    }

    readonly IMyClass _impl;
}

internal class MyClassImpl : IMyClass
{
    static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, IMyClass> _dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, IMyClass>();

    readonly int _n;

    MyClassImpl(int n)
    {
        _n = n;
    }

    public static IMyClass Create(int n)
    {
        return _dict.GetOrAdd(n, i => new MyClassImpl(i));
    }

    public int SomeMethod(int x)
    {
        return _n + x;
    }
}
```

Then client code can create instances of `MyClass`, and behind the scenes another class is used for the implementation.

If the client code creates two instances of MyClass, the implementing object will be shared, as this code demonstrates:

```
var a = new MyClass(1);
var b = new MyClass(2);
var c = new MyClass(1);

Console.WriteLine(a.ImplementationEquals(b)); // Prints false
Console.WriteLine(a.ImplementationEquals(c)); // Prints true
```

Also note that if you do something like this, it's very important that the class is strongly immutable (i.e. all of its fields are immutable, and if a field is not a primitive type, all of its fields are recursively immutable)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, C# does not allow you to change the result of the `new` operator. It always returns a new instance of class. Of course we are speaking about normal classes and not special hacks like `ContextBoundObject` and proxies.

So there is no way to keep your clients using the `new` operator and get the desired behavior. You need to remove the public constructors and force your clients to use some public static factory method like `MyClass.Create` (or `Construct` as in your example).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from your code, You want to provide the same object if user creates the same number for another instance. If then it is better to user factory pattern or singleton pattern

Answer (score 1):

Well, you seem to want only one instance of your class.

Would be easier to create a static class, no ?

```
public static class MyClass
{
    static MyClass()
    {
        n_ = 2;
    }

    private static int n_;

    public static void Construct(int number)
    {
        n_= number;
    }
}
```